# How to change fillColor of UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext?

Tags: ios, uiview, swift3, core-graphics

I've written this custom UIView class to draw custom shape

```
class ShapeView: UIView {

var color: UIColor?

init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.color = color
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    drawShape(rect: rect, color: self.color!)
}

func drawShape(rect: CGRect,color: UIColor) {
    guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: 0))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height / 2))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2 , y: rect.height))
    ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2))


    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
    ctx.fillPath()
    ctx.strokePath()
}

override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.frame)
    return path.contains(point)
}
```

and when the user pressed somewhere inside the shape I need to change the fillColor of this shape to let's say black with this code // while debugging the color didn't change it's look like I did something wrong.

in some UIViewController class I wrote this method

```
  class SomeClass: UIViewController {
   var shape1: ShapeView?
   var frame: CGRect?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
   let x = view.frame.midX
    let y = view.frame.midY

    self.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 100)
   super.viewDidLoad()
   self.shape1 = ShapeView(frame: frame!, color: .red)
    shape1?.backgroundColor = .clear
    view.addSubview(shape1!)
}
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let location = touches.first!.location(in: self.view)
    if (shape1?.point(inside: location, with: event))! {
        print("inside shape1")
        shape1?.drawShape(rect: frame!, color: .black)
    } else {
        print("outside shape1")
        shape1?.drawShape(rect: frame!, color: .red)
    }
  }
```

any ideas !

Comment: Where you are calling this `if (shape1?.point(inside: location, with: event))! {
        print("inside shape1")
        shape1?.drawShape(rect: frame!, color: .black)
    }` in another `ViewController` or in that same `ShapeView` class

Comment: whats the `shape1` there.... is it an UIView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't call your `drawShape()` func directly - it gets called every time the object paints itself:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    super.draw(rect)
    drawShape(rect: rect, color: self.color!)
}
```

So, it will immediately change the fill color back to `shape1`'s `color` property.

Instead, do something like this (not tested, just typing here):

```
if (shape1?.point(inside: location, with: event))! {
    print("inside shape1")
    shape1?.color = UIColor.black
} else {
    print("outside shape1")
    shape1?.color = UIColor.red
}
shape1?.setNeedsDisplay()
```

**Edit:** You can also modify your `ShapeView` class like this:

```
var color: UIColor? {
    didSet {
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

which would eliminate the need to "manually" call `.setNeedsDisplay()` in your touches handler.

***Edit #2:*** You can paste this into a Playground page and it should run without changes...

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ShapeView: UIView {

    var color: UIColor? {
        didSet {
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    init(frame: CGRect, color: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.color = color
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        drawShape(rect: rect, color: self.color!)
    }

    func drawShape(rect: CGRect,color: UIColor) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: 0))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height / 2))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2 , y: rect.height))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2))


        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        ctx.fillPath()
        ctx.strokePath()
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.frame)
        return path.contains(point)
    }
}

class VCA : UIViewController {

    var shape1: ShapeView?
    var frame: CGRect?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let x = view.frame.midX
        let y = view.frame.midY

        self.frame = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 100)
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.shape1 = ShapeView(frame: frame!, color: .red)
        shape1?.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.addSubview(shape1!)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = touches.first!.location(in: self.view)
        if (shape1?.point(inside: location, with: event))! {
            print("inside shape1")
            shape1?.color = UIColor.black
        } else {
            print("outside shape1")
            shape1?.color = UIColor.red
        }
    }

}

let vcA = VCA()
vcA.view.backgroundColor = .yellow
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vcA.view
```

Screen-Recording of result running in a playground page:

[image]

Comment: See ***Edit #2***

Comment: Use the "Show Assistant Editor" button to open the Timeline output (basically a simulator in a window). What do you mean "not working"? Are you not getting touches? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Well, I meant the touches weren't accurate enough, so this my fault not yours

Comment: Your code is working on the playground, but not on the Xcode project

Comment: I will ask again... ***What do you mean "not working"?*** Does it not run? Do you get error messages? Does it run and the code is triggered by the color doesn't change? Do you not even see the Shape? If you want help, you need to at least *try*...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149231/discussion-between-mohammad-eliass-alhusain-and-donmag).

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
import UIKit
class ShapeView: UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
       super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        drawShape(rect: rect)
    }

    func drawShape(rect: CGRect) {
        guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else
        { return }
        ctx.setFillColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)

        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2, y: 0))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width, y: rect.height / 2))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.width / 2 , y: rect.height))
        ctx.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: rect.height / 2))
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.fillPath()
        ctx.strokePath()
    }

    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: self.frame)
        return path.contains(point)
    }}
```

and

```
class SomeClass: UIViewController {
    var shape1: ShapeView?
    var frame: CGRect?

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        let x = view.frame.midX
        let y = view.frame.midY
         shape1 = ShapeView(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 100, height: 100))
        view.addSubview(shape1!)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let location = touches.first!.location(in: self.view)
        if (shape1?.point(inside: location, with: event))! {
            print("inside shape1")
            shape1?.backgroundColor = .green
        } else {
            print("outside shape1")
            shape1?.backgroundColor = .black
        }
}
}
```

Comment: I don't need the background color of the view, I need to fill the shape inside the view with another color